# spring io (gradle) front-end angularjs singup form not working

Tags: java, angularjs, forms, spring-mvc

[The error and the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsC4v.png)
Bellow i pasted The spring tool suite error msg-

> 2017-09-13 17:11:18.375 ERROR 6472 --- [nio-8080-exec-3]
>   org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             :
>   [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-3] Exception processing template
>   "register": Exception parsing document: template="register", line 6 -
>   column 3
>
> 2017-09-13 17:11:18.375 ERROR 6472 --- [nio-8080-exec-3]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Exception parsing
>   document: template="register", line 6 - column 3] with root cause.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MinMaxCtrl', function ($scope){
 $scope.formModel ={};
 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container main-content" ng-controller="MinMaxCtrl">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="formModel.email" id="email" required="required" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="formModel.name" id="name" required="required" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="formModel.password" id="password" required="required" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="age">age</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="formModel.age" id="age" required="required" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="gender">gender</label>
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="formModel.gender" id="gender" required="required" />
                <option value="">Please Choose</option>
                <option value="male">Male</option>
                <option value="female">Female</option>
                <option value="other">Other</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="weight">weight (kg)</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="formModel.weight" id="weight" required="required" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="height">height (cm)</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="formModel.height" id="height" required="required" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
            </div>
<pre>{{ formModel | json }}</pre>

        </form>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular-resource.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[The js fidle site.](https://jsfiddle.net/4chyfye4/1/)
So i went to a interview for this job and they gave me an assignment, i have to create a website: Java + angularjs with java spring framework + a mysql database.

Basically what i have is these Edit: three* links in 1 project

spring io/guides/gs/securing-web/

spring io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

spring io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/

plus a link to the singup site.
Cant get spring to load the signup site.

For clarity:

1. How can i make the singup site load?
2. How can i make spring upload the filed form to the mysql(i know how its done in php but not in this)

Comment: ok wow i just needed a /> for the link rel

Answer (score 0):

To connect your filled form to database, you can use Hibernate and JPA queries. You can create entity or POJO class for your form fields, make repositories and service implementation classes .
You can take help of "http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-form-handling-tutorial-and-example" this link for example.